# sizeof operator on array name when offset is added

Tags: c, arrays, sizeof, mingw32

I was curious about `sizeof(arrayName + offset)`. It gives me the `sizeof(pointer)`. Though array name is actually a constant pointer in C, `sizeof(arrayName)` gives the size in bytes of an array. So I guess the compiler treat `(arrayName+offset)` as pure pointer even for `sizeof()` and hence only exception while using the array name would be `sizeof(arrayName)`.

Is this behavior `sizeof(arrayName + offset)` well defined by the compiler? I am using MinGW 32 bit compiler.
Also is there any way we can know the size of partial array other than by using simple math like `(sizeof(arrayName) - offset*sizeof(arrayName[0]))`?

Is `sizeof(arrayName)` is not an inconsistent language construct in C/C++? For all other purpose, `arrayName` is treated as an address. And when we pass array to a function, this behavior may lead to bugs and beginners always have issue with this.

Comment: `arrayName + offset` causes `arrayName` to degrade to a pointer, so yes, this is well-defined. Yes, this behavior of arrays degrading to pointers is confusing to beginners; when you build your time machine, I suggest visiting Dennis Ritchie around 1969 and telling him not to do it. :-)

Comment: "array name is actually a constant pointer in C" - NO

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An array name is converted to a pointer to its first element in all but three cases:

- The operand of the address-of operator `&`
- The operand of the `sizeof` operator.
- The operand of the `_Alignof` operator.

This is detailed in section 6.3.2.1 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> *3* Except  when  it  is  the  operand  of  the `sizeof` operator, the `_Alignof` operator, or the unary `&` operator, or is a string 
>   literal  used  to  initialize  an  array, an expression  that  has
>   type "array of type" is converted to an expression with type "pointer
>   to type"  that  points to  the  initial  element  of  the  array 
>   object  and  is  not  an  lvalue.   If  the  array  object  has
>   register storage class, the behavior is undefined.

In the case of `sizeof(arrayName + offset)`, the operand of `sizeof` is the expression `arrayName + offset`.  The type of this expression is a pointer type, since `arrayName` is converted to a pointer in order to perform pointer arithmetic with `offset`.  So the `sizeof` expression evaluates to the size of a pointer.

In the case of `sizeof(arrayName)`, the operand of `sizeof` is an array, so it evaluated to the size of the array in bytes.

Both of these behaviors are well defined by the C standard.